# Relevanssi - Duplicate Searches logged

Tags: wordpress, relevanssi

I'm using (and loving) Relevanssi plugin for WordPress. Having a problem though with searches being logged twice in user searches.

[Found this comment in the plugin comments about it being a problem with the template](https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/query_posts/#comment-27081).

When digging around my search template, I just removed everything, then added things piecemeal until I had double results again.

This is the line in my search template that seems to be the trouble maker, but I don't necessarily see why.

```
<div style="background-image: url();"></div>
```

It makes 0 sense to me. If that bit of STATIC html is in the `content-search.php` template, I get double searches logged. If I remove it, or if all of the articles have `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`s, then I only get one search logged.

It seems to have something to do with `style="background-image:url();"` not having a value?

### Here's the bigger picture:

**search.php:**

```
<?php  
  global $wp_query;

  if ( $wp_query->found_posts > 12 ) {
    $search_count = '1 - ' . $wp_query->post_count . ' of ' . $wp_query->found_posts;
  } else {
    $search_count = $wp_query->post_count;
  }

?>
<div class="search-pg-header">
  <?php include get_template_directory() . '/templates/partials/search-form.php'; ?>
  <?php if ( get_search_query() !== '' ) { ?>
     <h1>Showing <?php echo $search_count; ?> results for <?php echo get_search_query() ?></h1>
  <?php } // end if ?>
</div>
<div class="posts-container">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'search' );
    endwhile;
  else: ?>
    <p>There are no articles that matched your search.</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
  <button>Show More</button>
<?php } // end if ?>
```

**content-search.php:**

```
<article data-link="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <div style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('card-white');?>);"></div>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php if (get_post_type() === 'post') { get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); } ?>
    <?php if ( has_excerpt() ) {?>
      <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <?php } //end if ?>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fresh install of Wordpress and tested out this bizarre theory with 2017 theme. True enough, if I add `<div style="background-image:url();"></div>` to the template `template-parts/post/content-excerpt.php` then duplicate searches are logged.

If that div has an image: `<div style="background-image:url(http://image.com);"></div>` only one search is logged.

[As Mikko Saari (Relevanssi) so kindly helped me with, this is actually unintended behavior from the browser](https://github.com/msaari/relevanssi/issues/5).

It's definitely nice to at least have an explanation for this.

I was able to prevent this by just putting a check to see if there was a bkgd image before I rendered the inline style to the page, and now I know to be much more careful with this kind of thing in the future!

```
$style = ! empty( get_the_post_thumbnail_url($the_post, 'card-white') ) ? 
         'style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($the_post, 'card-white') . ');"' : '';

<div class="article-card__img" <?php echo $style; ?>></div>
```